# Showing $f'(x)=2f(x)$

Tags: real-analysis

I am trying to show that given the following function,

$$f(x)=\sum _{n=0}^{\infty}  \frac{2^n}{n!}x^n$$

$f'(x)=2f(x)$

So,

$f'(x)= \sum _{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{2^nnx^{n-1}}{n!} = \sum _{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{2^nx^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}=\sum _{n=0}^{\infty}2\frac{(2x)^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}$

and,

$2f(x)= 2\sum _{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{2^n}{n!}x^n$

So how can I show they are equivalent?

Comment: f(x)  is a infinite sum, you're just differentiating the general term.

Comment: _They_ are not. But you have to _add_ them.

Comment: You might also note $f(x) = e^{2x}$ so $f'(x) = 2 e^{2x} = 2 f(x)$.

Comment: Note that the differentiated series starts from $$n=1$$, use $$k=n-1$$ as change of variable.

Comment: @A.Webb how do I show that $f(x)=e^{2x}$?

Comment: @us305 If you accept that $g(x) := e^x = \sum \frac{x^n}{n!}$ then evaluate $g(2x)$

Comment: $f'(x)= \sum _{n=0}^{\infty}2\frac{(2x)^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}$ is not quite right. Note what happens in that sum for $n=0$.

Answer (score 1):

the constant term $\frac {d}{dx} 2^0 x^0 = 0$

$f'(x)= \sum_\limits{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{2^n(nx^{n-1})}{n!} = \sum_\limits{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{2^nx^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}=2\sum_\limits{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(2x)^{n-1}}{(n-1)!} = 2\sum_\limits{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{2^nx^{n}}{(n)!} = 2f(x)$

Comment: what is this?$\frac {d}{dx} 2^0 x^0 = 0$

Comment: the derivative of the constant term of f(x) = 0.  This explains why the summation goes from 0 to infinity in f(x) to 1 to infinity in f'(x)

Comment: @us305 You have to treat the $n=0$ term separately. The $n=0$ term is $\frac{2^0}{0!}x^0=1$, and its derivative is $0$. Then you can do all the other terms using the general form, the way you did in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You lost the summation signs in your equations for $f'(x)$ and $f(x)$.  Those are important because the $n=1$ term in the sum for $f'(x)$ corresponds to the $n=0$ term in the sum for $f(x)$.  Restore the summation signs and see how it works.

Comment: I have edited them in

Answer (score 0):

Let's write things carefully

$$f'(x)=\sum_{\color{red}{n=1}}^\infty{2^n\cdot x^{n-1}\over (n-1)!}$$

Now let us change index $m=n-1$ and we can rewrite

$$f'(x)=\sum_{\color{red}{m=0}}^\infty2\cdot{2^mx^m\over m!}=\sum_{\color{red}{n=0}}^\infty2\cdot{2^nx^n\over n!}=f(2x)$$

$m$ being a dummy index.

Comment: thanks for your answer, did I calculate $f'(x)$ correctly?

Comment: No because your sum for $f'(x)$ starts at $n=0$ and it should start at $n=1$ ; by the way $x^{-1}$ has nothing to do in $f'(x)$ and $(-1)!$ makes hardly sense in this context.

Answer (score 0):

Since $f(x)$ is defined by a power series with an infinite radius of convergence we are allowed to perform termwise differentiation, leading to:
$$ f'(x)=\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{n 2^n}{n!} x^{n-1} = \sum_{m\geq 0}\frac{2^{m+1}}{m!}x^{m} = 2\,f(x) $$
as wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Note that:
$$ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{2^n x^n}{n!} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(2x)^n}{n!}$$
Since $$e^x = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n!}$$ then
 $f(x) = e^{2x}$ and so

$$f'(x) = 2e^{2x} = 2f(x)$$